# How to keep Collect[] result in order?

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials, order

For example,

```
Collect[(1 + x + Cos[s] x^2)^3, x]
```

gives the result

```
1 + 3 x + 3 x^5 Cos[s]^2 + x^6 Cos[s]^3 + x^2 (3 + 3 Cos[s]) + x^3 (1 + 6 Cos[s]) 
     + x^4 (3 Cos[s] + 3 Cos[s]^2)
```

Terms of the form $x^n$ are in random order. I would like the result is to be as follows:

```
 1 + 3 x + x^2 (3 + 3 Cos[s]) + x^3 (1 + 6 Cos[s]) +  
   x^4 (3 Cos[s] + 3 Cos[s]^2) + 3 x^5 Cos[s]^2 + x^6 Cos[s]^3
```

---

Well, First Thank you very much, Jens!
Second, I found there is something wrong with your statement "the HoldForm could be left out". I have tried on my mathematica 8, it turns out that the "HoldForm" is necessary . if "HoldForm" is not there, the order is still random in the output . And I tried to understand this as well as "rule" and "ruledelayed" stuff but can't figure it out. I have tried several input, each confused me. summarized as follows

1. `Replace[cx, List[x__] -> Plus[x]]`

   will give

   ```
   Sequence[1, 3 x, x^2 (3 + 3 Cos[s]), x^3 (1 + 6 Cos[s]), x^4 (3 Cos[s] + 3 Cos[s]^2), 3 x^5 Cos[s]^2, x^6 Cos[s]^3]
   ```

   But I suppose it should give the Plus result because

   ```
   Replace[cx, List[x__] -> jjj[x]]
   ```

   gives

   ```
   jjj[1, 3 x, x^2 (3 + 3 Cos[s]), x^3 (1 + 6 Cos[s]),  x^4 (3 Cos[s] + 3 Cos[s]^2), 3 x^5 Cos[s]^2, x^6 Cos[s]^3]
   ```
2. `Replace[cx, List[x__] -> HoldForm@Plus[x]]` gives the right result

   ```
   1 + 3 x + x^2 (3 + 3 Cos[s]) + x^3 (1 + 6 Cos[s]) +  x^4 (3 Cos[s] + 3 Cos[s]^2) + 3 x^5 Cos[s]^2 + x^6 Cos[s]^3
   ```
3. `Replace[cx, List[x__] :> Plus[x]]` gives

   ```
   1 + 3 x + 3 x^5 Cos[s]^2 + x^6 Cos[s]^3 + x^2 (3 + 3 Cos[s]) + x^3 (1 + 6 Cos[s]) + x^4 (3 Cos[s] + 3 Cos[s]^2)
   ```

   Although it gives the right plus result, the order is wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an approach that doesn't rely on undocumented features or on low-level box manipulations. We're dealing with a polynomial, so we can simply collect its coefficients and arrange them any way we like as follows:

```
c0 = Collect[(1 + x + Cos[s] x^2)^3, x];

cx = CoefficientList[c0, x] x^Range[0, Exponent[c0, x]]

(*
==> {1, 3 x, x^2 (3 + 3 Cos[s]), x^3 (1 + 6 Cos[s]), 
 x^4 (3 Cos[s] + 3 Cos[s]^2), 3 x^5 Cos[s]^2, x^6 Cos[s]^3}
*)

Replace[cx, List[x__] :> HoldForm[Plus[x]]]
```

> $1+3 x+x^2 (3+3 \cos (s))+x^3 (1+6 \cos (s))+x^4
>    \left(3 \cos (s)+3 \cos ^2(s)\right)+3 x^5 \cos
>    ^2(s)+x^6 \cos ^3(s)$

I've just assembled the desired form of the polynomial by creating a list `cx` of all terms up to the maximum power `Exponent[c0, x]`, and then turning that list into a sum by means of `Replace`. Here, the `HoldForm` was put in so that the output now can be arranged in any alternative order by permuting (or, in particular, reversing) the list `cx` before doing the `Replace`:

```
Replace[Reverse@cx, List[x__] :> HoldForm[Plus[x]]]
```

> $x^6 \cos ^3(s)+3 x^5 \cos ^2(s)+x^4 \left(3 \cos
>    (s)+3 \cos ^2(s)\right)+x^3 (1+6 \cos (s))+x^2
>    (3+3 \cos (s))+3 x+1$

The output is in held form, so if you apply `ReleaseHold` to it the order will revert back to the first version. The `HoldForm` could also be exploited to do further cosmetic changes on the expression, such as putting coefficients before the power of `x` - but you didn't ask for that.

**Edit**
In response to a follow-up question: the `Replace` command has `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) instead of `->` in it because the pattern indicated by `x__` has to be fed into the `Plus` only at the time when there is actually a list of terms present. E.g., if you use `List[x__] -> Plus[x]` then the right-hand side is immediately evaluated to give you `x` as the result of `Plus[x]` (assuming that `x` hasn't been defined globally). And when you then later encounter the `Replace` statement it will say to feed the pattern inside `List` into the right-hand side that now has the form `x` instead of `Plus[x]`. That will yield something with the head `Sequence` corresponding to the sequence of arguments inside the given `List`.

Comment: I admit that's better. +1

Comment: Hello! Jens! I have some more questions, and post it as an "answer" below, would you please help me figure them out?

Comment: @user15964 Yes, I think my statement about `HoldForm` is confusing. I think I wanted to say that it's not needed if you want to replace a list by a sum, but of course it's needed to preserve the desired order as I tried to say afterwards. I'll edit this, but you should delete your answer because you're not supposed to write follow-up questions that way.

Comment: Thank you! finally, All is clear.

Answer (score 23):

You can use `PolynomialForm` :

```
Collect[(1 + x + Cos[s] x^2)^3, x] // PolynomialForm[#, TraditionalOrder -> True] &
```

> ```
> Cos[s]^3 x^6 + 3 Cos[s]^2 x^5 + (3 Cos[s]^2 + 3 Cos[s]) x^4 + (6 Cos[s] + 1) x^3
>  + (3 Cos[s] + 3) x^2 + 3 x + 1
> ```

Comment: Thank you! it's really worked! But why I can't find the "polynomialForm" entry in mathematica document centre?? And is there any other order except traditional order? How about keep order from low to high instead of high to low?

Comment: @user15964 `PolynomialForm` is undocumented. You can evaluate e.g. `Options[PolynomialForm]` which yields only `{TraditionalOrder -> Automatic}`.  More on useful undocumented functions you can find here : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions.  On the other hand you can get almost the same result with documented `TraditionalForm` : e.g. `expr // TraditionalForm`.

Comment: @Artes Is there any undocumented `MultivariatePolynomialForm`  function like `PolynomialForm`?

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes `PolynomialForm` works for multi-variable polynomials as well.

Comment: @Artes `PolynomialForm[b*x*y^3 + x^2 + a*x + y + y^2, {x, y}]` How to get the sorting result of  the binary polynomials according to the sum of index of the specified variables：`a*x + y + x^2 + y^2 + b*x*y^3`.

Answer (score 6):

Artes shows how to use `TraditionalOrder`, but user15964 asks "How about keep order from low to high instead of high to low?"  This can be done by manipulating the Box structure output of `PolynomialForm`.  First a look at that box structure:

```
tradOrder = PolynomialForm[#, TraditionalOrder -> True] &;
boxes = Collect[(1 + x + Cos[s] x^2)^3, x] // tradOrder // ToBoxes;
boxes // Shallow
```

> ```
> TagBox[RowBox[{<<13>>}], <<2>>&]
> ```

The row of terms is held as the elements skeletonized as `<<13>>`.  This list is at part `{1, 1}` of the `boxes` expression, so if we `MapAt` `Reverse` onto this position, and then show the boxes with `DisplayForm` we get:

```
MapAt[Reverse, boxes, {1, 1}] // DisplayForm
```

> ```
>  1 + 3 x + (3 Cos[s] + 3) x^2 + (6 Cos[s] + 1) x^3 + (3 Cos[s]^2 + 3 Cos[s]) x^4 
>   + 3 Cos[s]^2 x^5 + Cos[s]^3 x^6
> ```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that a clean yet undocumented method has existed since v5.2 or earlier that could be applied here.  Please reference [Undocumented fourth parameter of Collect; how long has it been there?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88781/undocumented-fourth-parameter-of-collect-how-long-has-it-been-there) and then observe:

```
Collect[(1 + x + Cos[s] x^2)^3, x, # &, Defer[+##] &]
```

> ```
> 1 + 3 x + x^2 (3 + 3 Cos[s]) + x^3 (1 + 6 Cos[s]) + x^4 (3 Cos[s] + 3 Cos[s]^2) + 
>  3 x^5 Cos[s]^2 + x^6 Cos[s]^3
> ```

Or in reverse:

```
Collect[(1 + x + Cos[s] x^2)^3, x, # &, Defer[+##] ~Reverse~ 2 &]
```

> ```
> x^6 Cos[s]^3 + 3 x^5 Cos[s]^2 + x^4 (3 Cos[s] + 3 Cos[s]^2) + x^3 (1 + 6 Cos[s]) + 
>  x^2 (3 + 3 Cos[s]) + 3 x + 1
> ```