# Changing order of TeXForm output

Tags: output-formatting

I am creating Taylor polynomials and exporting them using `TeXForm`. When a polynomial `p[x]` is displayed in *Mathematica*, it shows, for instance, `1+x+x^2+x^3`. However, `TeXForm` always reverses the polynomial, giving it with largest power first:

`TeXForm[p[x]] = x^3+x^2+x+1`.

How can I keep the polynomial in the same order? Taylor polynomials are generally thought of as being constructed from low-to-high powers, so reading them in the generated format is a bit confusing to some.

Comment: A related question that might be of interest: [how to keep “collect” result in order?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15744/245)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [HoldForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldForm.html):

```
In[]:= TeXForm[HoldForm[1 + x + x^2 + x^3]]

Out[]//TeXForm= 1+x+x^2+x^3
```

Or for a function `p[x]` evaluating to a polynomial:

```
In[9]:= TeXForm[HoldForm[Evaluate[p[x]]]]

Out[9]//TeXForm=
1+x+x^2+x^3
```

Comment: This works if I copy/paste the output into `TeXForm[HoldForm[...]]`; I'd rather it be done automatically. Using "`TeXForm[HoldForm[p[x]]]`" just returns "`p(x)`".

Comment: How about TeXForm[HoldForm[Evaluate[p[x]]]]?

Comment: Your answer works. If it were a separate answer, I'd accept it; it is more elegant than using an undocumented command.

Comment: Answer edited to add the form for a function p[x].

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the undocumented (and probably deprecated, so beware!) `PolynomialForm`.

```
poly = Expand[(1+x)^10]

TeXForm@PolynomialForm[poly, TraditionalOrder -> False]

(* ==> "1+10 x+45 x^2+120 x^3+210 x^4+252 x^5+210 x^6+120 x^7+45 x^8+10 x^9+x^{10}" *)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but using `TeXForm[HoldForm[Evaluate[p[x]]]]` is probably better.