# Simplifying symbolic expression using replacement rules

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, rule

I am trying to carry out a linear stability analysis of a two PDE system. I start by defining the equations and then define the perturbation along with the replacement rules required. I then use a series of commands to linearize the equations and come up with the coefficients to the linearized system given by $Au=0$ where $A$ is a 2x2 matrix and $u$ is the equilibrium states of my solution variables. I then find that one of my coefficients is given by:
$$
a_{11}= \frac{\phi_0\omega\eta_1}{V_0}+\frac{\omega\eta_2}{V_0}-\frac{\phi_0\omega\eta_2}{V_0}
$$
Now the command I used for this output is:

```
a11=Collect[Coefficient[equh0,Overscript[h, ^]],k,#1 &,Defer[+##1]&]/. Subscript[\[Eta], 
1] \[Phi]0-Subscript[\[Eta], 2] \[Phi]0+Subscript[\[Eta], 2]->Subscript[V, 0]
```

My question is this: why is Mathematica not simplifying the coefficient for $k^0$. If you look at it, the fractions can be combined and then one can see that you should get $\frac{\omega V_0}{V_0} = \omega$. But if I add another replacement rule of the form

```
Subscript[\[Eta], 2] \[Omega]+Subscript[\[Eta], 1] \[Omega] \[Phi]0-Subscript[\[Eta], 2] \[Omega] \[Phi]0->Subscript[V, 0] \[Omega]
```

Nothing changes. Similarly, if I try add the command Simplify[] or FullSimplify[] on the outside of the Collect[] function nothing changes. So why can't Mathematica simplify this? It's not a huge deal right now as these coefficients are currently simple enough for me to manipulate them by hand, however, I would like to make some modifications which is going to add a bunch of terms and I would like to avoid hand calculations if possible. So how can I make Mathematica actually simplify this as much as possible?

EDIT: To address the comment about why Collect[] has four arguments, see the answer by Mr. Wizard to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15744/how-to-keep-collect-result-in-order). It evaluates fine on my end and is used so that the output is in ascending orders of $k$ (solely for visual purposes).

Comment: Your first bit of code defining `a11` doesn't evaluate.  First of all, `Collect` doesn't take four arguments.  Second, you've got `Overscript[h, ^]`, which definitely is syntactically incorrect.  Can you edit your post to include the correct executable code here?

Comment: That said, this kind of question has been asked a lot.  With replacement rules, you have to match the pattern *exactly*, and it is easiest to do with that with simpler expressions.  YOu want to do something like replace `Subscript[\[Eta], 1]` by "solving" your replacement rule for it, i.e., writing instead `Subscript[\[Eta], 1] -> (
 Subscript[V, 0] - Subscript[\[Eta], 2] + \[Phi]0 Subscript[\[Eta], 2])/\[Phi]0`

Comment: The first line of code doesn't execute because I would need to give the entire script, i.e. equh0 which then requires more definitions as well. Should I edit the answer to include the entire script? Also, see my edit for why I give collect four arguments.

Comment: Instead of `Overscript[h, ^]` presumably you mean `OverHat[h]`

Comment: @Mjoseph Always post working code. If you think the code is too long, reduce it to a *minimal working example* that shows the issue. This allows us to copy and paste your code directly and start experimenting with the code, which is typically what people do: we don't just *think* at the problem; we have to test our ideas, and having working code to start with is really helpful.